# Android Picasso - download video thumbnail from web

Tags: android, thumbnails, picasso

How to download a video thumbnail from web with Picasso library? Is that possible? If not, what are the alternatives? Glide?

Comment: What video thumbnail are you talking about? Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are talking about YouTube thumbnail, then you can easily do it with Picasso.

```
String youTubeBaseUrl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/[video_id]/0.jpg";
String regexPattern = "\\[video_id\\]";


public final void loadYouTubeThumbnail(String videoId, ImageView imageView) {
    picasso.load(buildYouTubeUrl(videoId))
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Here you replace [video_id] in youTubeBaseUrl with appropriate videoId(usually it looks something like "5qi51YrQOzo")

```
    private String buildYouTubeUrl(String videoId) {
        return youTubeBaseUrl.replaceAll(regexPattern, videoId);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm interested in the opportunity to take thumbnail of the video without using the features of a particular web api.

Comment: For example. How can I get thumbnail from this url: http://some/awesome/api/video.mp4

Comment: Well, I guess this will be tricky. Android does have native utils for this one(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html), but video has to be on a device, so the solution will be to download video on a device, and then extract a thumbnail from it, but it sounds like a bad idea lol. I will vote up your question, as universal thumbnails extractor sounds interesting.